# CreateFile Failed: 5

Tags: windows, winapi, driver, wdk, umdf

I'm new in windows driver.
I downloaded [this sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/WudfVhidmini-Sample-b304f83a) and fixed nothing but a report descriptor like this.

```
HID_REPORT_DESCRIPTOR           G_DefaultReportDescriptor[] = {
0x06, 0x00, 0xFF,                // USAGE_PAGE (Vender Defined Usage Page)
0x09, 0x01,                      // USAGE (Vendor Usage 0x01)
0xA1, 0x01,                      // COLLECTION (Application)
0x85, CONTROL_FEATURE_REPORT_ID,    // REPORT_ID (1)
0x09, 0x01,                         // USAGE (Vendor Usage 0x01)
0x15, 0x00,                         // LOGICAL_MINIMUM(0)
0x26, 0xff, 0x00,                   // LOGICAL_MAXIMUM(255)
0x75, 0x08,                         // REPORT_SIZE (0x08)
//0x95,FEATURE_REPORT_SIZE_CB,       // REPORT_COUNT 
0x96, (FEATURE_REPORT_SIZE_CB & 0xff), (FEATURE_REPORT_SIZE_CB >> 8), // REPORT_COUNT 
0xB1, 0x00,                         // FEATURE (Data,Ary,Abs)
0x09, 0x01,                         // USAGE (Vendor Usage 0x01)
0x75, 0x08,                         // REPORT_SIZE (0x08)
//0x95,INPUT_REPORT_SIZE_CB,       // REPORT_COUNT 
0x96, (INPUT_REPORT_SIZE_CB & 0xff), (INPUT_REPORT_SIZE_CB >> 8), // REPORT_COUNT 
0x81, 0x00,                         // INPUT (Data,Ary,Abs)
0x09, 0x01,                         // USAGE (Vendor Usage 0x01)
0x75, 0x08,                         // REPORT_SIZE (0x08)
//0x95,OUTPUT_REPORT_SIZE_CB,      // REPORT_COUNT 
0x96, (OUTPUT_REPORT_SIZE_CB & 0xff), (OUTPUT_REPORT_SIZE_CB >> 8), // REPORT_COUNT 
0x91, 0x00,                         // OUTPUT (Data,Ary,Abs)
0xC0,                           // END_COLLECTION
};
```

to

```
HID_REPORT_DESCRIPTOR           G_DefaultReportDescriptor[] = {
0x05,0x01,                      // USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
0x09,0x02,                      // USAGE (Mouse)
0xA1,0x01,                      // COLLECTION (Application)
0x85,0x01,                      // REPORT_ID (1)
0x09,0x01,                         // USAGE (Pointer)
0xA1,0x00,                         // COLLECTION (Physical)
0x05,0x09,                         // USAGE Page (Buttons)
0x19,0x01,                         // USAGE Minimum (01)
0x29,0x03,                         // USAGE Maximum (03)
0x15,0x00,                         // LOGICAL_MINIMUM(0)
0x25,0x01,                         // LOGICAL_MAXIMUM(1)
0x95,0x03,                         // REPORT_COUNT (3)
0x75,0x01,                         // REPORT_SIZE (1)
0x81,0x02,                         // Input (Data, Variable, Absolute)
0x95,0x01,                         // REPORT_COUNT (1)
0x75,0x05,                         // REPORT_SIZE (5)
0x81,0x03,                         // Input (Constant)
0x05,0x01,                         // USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
0x09,0x30,                         // Usage (X)
0x09,0x31,                         // Usage (Y)
0x15,0x81,                         // LOGICAL_MINIMUM(-127)
0x25,0x7F,                         // LOGICAL_MAXIMUM(127)
0x75,0x08,                         // REPORT_SIZE (8)
0x95,0x02,                         // REPORT_COUNT (2)
0x81,0x06,                         // Input (Data, Variable, Relative)
0xC0,                           // END_COLLECTION
0xC0                            // END_COLLECTION
};
```

The results:
1. Successfully installed as a HID mouse.
2. Running testApp, CreateFile Failed like this.

....looking for our HID device

> Error: CreateFile failed: 5
>   Failure: Could not find our HID device

Please help me. I couldn't figure out why this happened.

Comment: Did the original sample work for you?

Comment: `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` has the value 5. Do you run the application with the necessary rights? Try to run "as administrator" and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: @user1793036 Yes, it did.

Comment: @MartinLiversage I know and tried but it didn't work. I think this is not that problem.